# ExtJS 4 Track all events for a component

Tags: extjs, extjs4

For debugging purposes I want to track all events for a certain component (combo, form, etc.) so I could see when and what events have fired for this component.

Is there a common approach to tracking all events without creating specific listeners?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `Ext.util.Observable` for this purpose. Let's say the reference is `myCombo`:

```
Ext.util.Observable.capture(myCombo, function(){console.log(arguments)});
```

I use this one-liner quite often from the console to see the fired events.